# Visual studio compilation error, Xamarin.forms

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I create Hello world project in Visual Studio 2015 based on Xamarin.forms(portable), but when I try to build, I get the following error:

> Cannot find `aapt.exe`. Please install the Android SDK Build-tools package with the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\android.bat` program.   App3.Droid

My android SDK manager:
[image]

I had older version of sdk platform tools, but Visual Studio give me an error that you have remove older version of sdk tools than 23.0.0

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2019 you can fix this inside Visual Studio.

Simply go to Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager and either repair or install the recommended versions.

In my case I had this error:

> XA5205 Cannot find `aapt.exe`. Please install the Android SDK
> Build-Tools package with the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\android.bat` program.

I could then click on this error to let Visual Studio fix it for me:

> Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio requires Android SDK. Please click
> here to configure.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do not remove `platform-tools`, there are three core Google/Android platform packages needed for building apps:

- build-tools
- platform-tools
- tools

And `aapt.exe` is located within in `build-tools`, not `platform-tools` and it appears you are missing that package installation.

[image]

#### Open up Android SDK Manager and perform a "Packages \ Reload".

[image]

If a `build-tools` package does show up I would reinstall the Android SDK.

**Note**: Your Android SDK Manager looks really different then the current version, what version is that? (mine is v23)

[image]

Comment: My Android SDK Manager version is 24.4.1

Comment: I can install `Build-tools` But now I get Another error: ` Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' available in SDK installer.`

Comment: @user3748973 If you are still having a problem with this other/new issue. I would recommend posting a new question. That way each Question/Answer set is about one solving one unique issue (the Stackoverlfow way of life :-) so your new problem will be seen by everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and Delete all from the path: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Xamarin Folders and Zip files. And then rebuild your project.